# Menu scrolling issue

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a problem with the scrolling of my anchor links.

As you can see it is jumpy/glitchy and I have no idea why and where to look to solve this.
(Using WordPress, elementor and this function to smooth out the scroll).

I tried also "Page to Id" plugin but for some reason it becomes more jumpy and has a weird behavior even if I check the option to block any other scrolling script.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
function smooth_scroll() {
?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".page-id-27 ul.primary-menu.reset-list-style li a").on('click', function(event) {
            // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
            if (this.hash !== "") {
              // Prevent default anchor click behavior
              event.preventDefault();

              // Store hash
              var hash = this.hash;

              // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
              // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
              $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 100
            }, 900);
            return false;
            } // End if
          });
        });
    </script>
<?php
```

}

Comment: `function smooth_scroll() {
?>
    <script>` this looks really syntax-starnge. Try to code in any IDE with coding assistance.

Comment: header-inner element is having the class shrink set then removed then set again, try removing animate effect (to zero) from scroll click, to see if the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the scrolling behavior was caused by the TwentyTwenty WordPress theme.

The scroll implemented in the TwentyTwenty theme is/was broken. 
To fix this issue I used the following:

1. Update the theme.
2. Add the following code to your child theme CSS:
   html {scroll-behavior: auto !important;}
3. Install "Page to ID" WordPress plugin and easily handle your scrolling.

Thank you for the help guys, I really appreciate it.